# question about UNIX dig output

Tags: unix, dns, mx-record, dig

Using the unix `dig` command, I can get the following MX record:

```
$ dig +nocmd gmail.com MX +noall +answer

gmail.com.      1868    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1868    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1868    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1868    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1868    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

My question is, what does the fifth column (20, 40, 5...) mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers give the relative preference of the MX records. Lower values are more preferred. See [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)

Answer (score 0):

It's the "Priority" of the MX records, some people have two sets of MX records using the secondary MX records as a backup.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Not sure how you found this, but you should note that it was asked in 2009... I've kind of moved on from this project :)  If you want to answer some of the more current questions, see the main [StackOverflow page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/).